# Why does my CSS selector does not work as expected?

Tags: html, css

I am creating a gallery website my goal is the show option button on bottom of the picture when use hover over it. 
Here is an example of what I want on [pixabay](http://pixabay.com/)

```
<div class="image-thumbnail col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
    <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/400x300" alt="">
    </a>
    <div class="image-options">
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm ">
                <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm ">
                <i class="fa fa-thumbs-down"></i>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm">
                <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm">
                <i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm">
                <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.image-thumbnail div.image-options {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2000;
    margin-top: -55px;
    margin-left: 1px;
    display: none;
}
div.image-thumbnail div.image-options:hover {
    display: inline;
}
```

Any ideas ?

***EDIT:***

It turns out that

```
div.image-thumbnail  div.image-options {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2000;
    margin-top: -55px;
    margin-left: 1px;
    display: none;
}
```

Don't work at all as the `image-options`  are still visible even with `display:none`

Comment: Without really looking at it I'm going to guess you want `div.image-thumbnail:hover div.image-options`. You want options to display when you hover over the thumbnail, not when you hover over options (as it is hidden this isn't possible).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't hover element with `display: none`, it's not visible. Instead you should define `:hover` rule on `.image-thumbnail` element:

```
.image-thumbnail {
    position: relative;
}
.image-thumbnail .image-options {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2000;
    margin-top: -55px;
    margin-left: 1px;
    display: none;
}
.image-thumbnail:hover .image-options {
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: Check the demo, it should work: http://plnkr.co/edit/h36D8sw4l92BoHZe5tWw?p=preview

Comment: I see it is working and this is exactly what I am looking for however it still don't work with my code ... I've checked that CSS is actually attached and everything else but still not working :(

Comment: When I remove .image-thumbnail from in front of .image-options it works i.e when I keep the style like this  .image-options {
    position: absolute !important;
    z-index: 2000 !important;
    margin-top: -55px !important;
    margin-left: 1px !important;
    display: none !important;
}
 this is Ok but .image-thumbnail .image-options { is not OK !

Comment: Done this has something to do with HTML doctype css3 or something like that as I am not CSS/HTML expert :(

Comment: Then it means that `.image-options` is not a child of `.image-thumbnail`. Check your HTML structure.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in my comment.

```
div.image-thumbnail div.image-options:hover {
    display: inline;
}
```

This is saying when we hover over `div.image-options` display it... This isn't possible. (As you have it set to `display: none`) plus this is not the element you want to set the hover on.

What you mean to say is

```
div.image-thumbnail:hover div.image-options {
    display: inline;
}
```

When we hover over `div.image-thumbnail` then show `div.image-options`.